# Meteor packages almost always fail to install

Tags: meteor

My experience with meteor has always been the same: a few packages install with `mrt add` but most of them exit with some error.

Errors such as

1. `Template names shouldn't contain '.' or '/'`
2. `Parse error: ...    {{> yield region='menu'}}`
3. `There was a problem checking out tag: v0.6.1`
4. `error: File not found: lib/moment/moment.js`
5. `Parse error: ... afFieldMessage name=field autoform=../.`

These were some of the errors I was presented with when I just now tried to do `mrt add` with `houston`, `ogno-admin`, `autoform`, `tabs`, `issues`, and `wizard`.

I realize this is a vague question, but *what am I doing wrong?*

Do other people have this experiene with meteor? It would be a really easy way to build lots of different apps if only it worked at all!

Comment: Are you using the the 0.8.0 version? I guess most of the packages hasn't been updated to work with the latest Meteor release yet :/

Comment: That was with 0.7; After running `meteor update` to 0.8, I get the same errors installing packages.

Comment: Perhaps you've installed something with `sudo`? If you experience problems with most packages the problem is most likely with your setup rather than with packages themselves. The most common error is installing `meteor` or `mrt` with `sudo`, which causes problems with file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Meteorite is wonky sometimes. If you are seeing random errors like this, you may want to follow the cleanup instructions for Meteorite, and make sure you are using the latest version. The `moment` error you're seeing above happens, for example, when Meteorite fails to check out the [git submodule in meteor-moment](https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment/tree/master/lib).

Make sure you're up to date.

```
sudo -H npm update -g meteorite
```

Then, quoted from [Meteorite troubleshooting](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md):

```
  mrt uninstall
  mrt uninstall --system
  mrt install .
```

One other thing, mentioned in the comments, is that unmaintained packages that use the UI will very likely be broken in Meteor 0.8. So don't confuse that with Meteorite errors.